# How do I access the same data across multiple controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Firstly forgive my lack of knowledge as I'm just starting out with MVC development. I'm currently developing a web application that reads/writes from/to a SQL Server Database using the WebMatrix.Data provider for the most my views will all have different requirements and thus will have different SQL blocks in each controller (to be pulled through by individual data models). That's all fine!

But I want to store my sites settings in SQL table as well and these settings need to be reused across every view and even the layout page. Now I could individually map each column to my settings model and then pull that through in my views on an individual basis - but that seems like an awful lot of duplication.

I'm thinking that I could create a reusable class for accessing the settings table, but I'm struggling to visualize how that would work. Could someone provide me with an example of how it can be done?

Comment: I'm using settings classes serialized down to the database using `BinaryFormatter`.

Comment: Could you provide an example of this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Singleton pattern will help you.

> Singleton is using when you need a class that has only one instance, and you need to provide a global point of access to the instance.

See more: 
Example of singleton pattern applied to ASP.Net MVC application:
[How to create a perfect Singleton class in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10239765/how-to-create-a-perfect-singleton-class-in-c)

http://www.alexzaitzev.pro/2013/02/singleton-pattern.html